# Why is there something written in the data section of an ICMPv4 echo ping request?

Tags: wireshark, icmp

(My question differs from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552134/what-data-is-included-in-icmp-ping-request) one.)
I am connected to a AP in a wireless network and I've send a simple ping request to *www.google.com*. When I analyze the packet in wireshark, I can see, that there are 48 bytes written in the data section of ICMP. After 8 bytes of trash values, the values are sequentially increasing from `0x10` to `0x37`.
Is there any particular reason, why ICMPv4 fits values instead of just using a bunch of zeroes?

The hexdump of the ICMPv4 data section:

```
0030         09 d9 0d 00 00 00 00 00 10 11 12 13 14 15     .Ù............
0040   16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 20 21 22 23 24 25   .......... !"#$%
0050   26 27 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f 30 31 32 33 34 35   &'()*+,-./012345
0060   36 37                                             67
```

Comment: Why not take a look at [the ICMP RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc792)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*After 8 bytes of trash values*

First of all, these are not *trash values*.  In [some implementations](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sbin/ping/ping.c?view=markup#l1010) of `ping`, the 1st 8 bytes may represent a timestamp.

As @ross-jacobs mentioned, [RFC 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792) describes the ICMP Echo Request/Reply Packets.  For clarity, these two packets are described, in relevant part, as follows:

Echo or Echo Reply Message

```
    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |     Type      |     Code      |          Checksum             |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |           Identifier          |        Sequence Number        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |     Data ...
   +-+-+-+-+-

   ...

   Description

      The data received in the echo message must be returned in the echo
      reply message.
```

Here you can see that the contents of the Data is not described at all; therefore an implementation is free to use whatever data it wishes, including none at all.

Now, since `ping` is a network test tool, one of the things it can help test is fragmentation/reassembly.  Every `ping` implementation I'm aware of allows the user to specify the size of the payload, and if you exceed the MTU, you should see the ICMP packet fragmented/reassembled.  If you examine the payload of the first fragment, you can tell where the second fragment should start just by looking at the sequence of bytes in the payload of the first fragment.  If the data was all 0's, it wouldn't be possible to do this.  Similarly, if an ICMP packet wasn't reassembled properly, not only would the checksum likely be wrong, but you would most likely be able to tell exactly where the reassembly failed due to a gap or other inconsistency in the payload.  This is just one example of why a payload with a sequence of bytes instead of all 0's is more useful to the user.